# Как можно кликнуть на этот элемент?

Tags: c#, selenium

Всё, что имеется - это всего-лишь:

```
<a href="тут ссылка" rel="nofollow">опять ссылка</a>
```

Пробовал так:

`driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector([rel*='nofollow']));`

Но вроде как бесполезно :c

Вот так это выглядит: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И вот полный DOM

`<br/>Создать аккаунт:
<br/>
<a href="test.com/?stoken=f600df4f85e" rel="nofollow">test.com/?stoken=f600df4f85e77f</a>
<br/>`

Как с помощью selenium'a можно кликнуть на этот элемент?

Comment: Если ссылка уникальная, то `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector('a[href="тут ссылка"]')).click();`

Comment: @suit В этом то и проблема. У ссылки только одна часть неизменяемая, а вторая - генерируется.

Comment: Ну так опишите это нормально в вопросе. Тогда вам помогут, сейчас ничего не ясно. Плюс добавьте часть DOM, вокруг вашей ссылки, возможно там есть что-то постоянное, на что можно ориентироваться

Comment: @suit вокруг пустой текст и более ничего

Comment: А есть идеи, почему я не могу кликнуть по rel="nofollow"? Элемент с таким параметром только один на всей странице

Comment: А какая ошибка?

Comment: Ошибки никакой нет, просто программа не продолжает работу дальше, а зависает на месте

Comment: `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@rel='nofollow']"));` тоже не находит

Comment: xpath нормальный, у меня в таком виде все работает. Что-то вы упускаете. Может у вас не на этом месте зависание происходит

Comment: `MessageBox.Show("1"); 
var test = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@rel='nofollow']")); MessageBox.Show("2"); MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(test.Count())); test.ElementAt(0).Click(); 
MessageBox.Show("3");`
Первый и второй messagebox появляется, далее в третьем пишет, что таких элементов 0 и четвертый messagebox уже не появляется.

Comment: @suit добавил скрин + фулл DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если то, что вы указали в вопросе, и есть полный html на странице, то получается у вас единственная ссылка, которую просто находим по тегу:

```
driver.FindElementByTagName("a").Click();
```

Comment: Действительно сработало
Правда, странно, что через Xpath и CssSelector не работало, но да ладно, тут у меня скорее всего где-то косяк.
Спасибо большое